Am I right in calculating my schematics?
I’m studying electronics at university, but I didn’t quite understand the topic. Experts, could you check if my calculations for the first two circuits are correct? And please help me understand how to calculate the third one. Just a note—I’d prefer not to use any software tools, as I want to grasp the principles behind the calculations.
Source of the images: "Course handout, paper 45,10 and 9, Moscow Engineering Physics Institute”
On this images B means Volts, A means Amperes (amp),мА means mA(\$10^{-3}\$ amps), кОм means kOhm, мкФ means μF,
Here’s the first circuit.
And I have a question about it right away. The diode has two characteristics given: Uforward—as I understand, this is the voltage at which the diode starts conducting in the forward direction, and Rforward—I don’t quite understand the meaning of this resistance. My guess is that if the voltage exceeds Uforward, the total voltage drop across the diode would be Uforward + I*Rforward. But I’m not entirely sure. However, I used this approach for my calculations.
Task translation: Determine: how the diodes are shifted - forward or backward; 2) the potential of point A relative to the common pin ("ground"); 3) the current of the diode D3.
Values are in the table.
Silicon diodes with the following parameters are used in the circuit: U(Diod Forward)= 0.7V, R(Diod Forward)=100 ohms, (in reverse bias, the diode is considered a circuit break).

This is the second circuit.
It seems to be a simple transient process in an RC circuit. I think my calculations are correct, but I’d appreciate it if someone could double-check.
Task translation: Draw the dependence Uoutput(It is U on the right of this photo) for the RC circuit if a pulse is applied to the input U(it is on the left of this photo). Write an expression for the time constant of the RC circuit and calculate it. The amplitude of the input pulse is +5 V. The duration of the input pulse is t5.0 ms.

And finally, the third circuit.
Honestly, I tried following the steps we were taught—going through each path from + to ground—but the system ended up being incorrect. My attempt is shown, but there are errors somewhere. I don’t quite understand how to approach these calculations.
Task translation:
Determine the areas of operation of transistors T1 T2 and T3. Transistors parametrs:  U(base-emitter)=0.7 V, U(base-collector)=0.5 V, r(it is a base resistance) = 0.2 kOhm, β = 50.


@greybeard, Cyrillic is the correct word (I know because my name is Cyril :-)

(The Roman B is a "false friend" of the Cyrillic В; The correct Roman letter is V.)
